# Android's RecyclerView example misunderstanding

Tags: java, android, layout

I'm trying to follow the example here:

https://developer.android.com/training/material/lists-cards.html#RecyclerView

And there's a part which isn't very clear to me.

```
@Override
    public BlogPostAdapter.ViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent,
                                                   int viewType) {
        // create a new view
        View v = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                .inflate(R.layout.my_text_view, parent, false);
        ViewHolder vh = new ViewHolder(v);
        return vh;
    }
```

In this part, they are inflating a layout with "my_text_view".
I'm having trouble recreating this layout.
If I create a single xml file "my_text_view.xml" with a just a TextView, it won't compile. If I surround my TextView with "LinearLayout" I will fail to cast it to TextView for the example to work.
Create just a just a TextView with an ID and trying to inflate it will fail since that method takes a Layout as a parameter not a view.

How could I make this my_text_view layout for this example to work?

Answer (score 1):

It should compile using just a TextView inside the layout file.
Just make sure to add the xmlns:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Textview xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/text_view"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"/>
```

If you would want to wrap it inside a parent layout, when setting the viewHolder, you need to obtain the textview you're interested in from the view you inflate. You can obtain it by calling

```
view.findViewById(R.id.text_view);
```

Comment: trying to run that gives me android.view.InflateException: Binary XML file line #2: Error inflating class Textview

Comment: can you paste some code? layout maybe? bind method?